I recently resigned from my job and a confidentiality contract was violated
I recently resigned from my job of 2 years.
When I signed that contract I was told that no information of why I was resigning would be revealed to anyone.
My grandpa also worked with me. The manager that was present apparently decided to take it upon herself to tell him even after the contract was signed saying it was confidential.
Should I take this to HR?

What you were told doesn't matter. What is in the paperwork you signed when resigning might. But honestly, since this was given to a relative rather than to someone who might not hire you based on this information, you are going to have a very hard time showing that you have been harmed.

What are you hoping to gain by bringing this to HR? Is your goal to see the former manager disciplined or fire? Or is to get financial compensation for breaking the contract?  Or is it something else?

Your question is confusing. You resigned. Normally, no reason is needed for that. But you gave one anyway, but then signed a new contract that they may not tell anyone? And then they told another employee of theirs, that happens to be your grandparent. I think you need to add more information to that question for us to make any sense of it and give good advice. For example, how did they tell your grandpa? As a part of their job, or as gossip in the break room? What exactly did that contract say that supposedly forbade it?

I assure you, the contract you signed was to ensure that you don't reveal anything confidential, not the other way around.
Your former manager revealed to another employee at the company that you don't work at the company anymore after your resigned? This is a nothingburger.
Your grandpa, who is likely been there longer and more well connected with more people at the company, would have found out anyway. You just can't stop the gossip mill.


I was told that no information of why I was resigning would be revealed to anyone.

So you don't want that information to be revealed, yet you told someone anyway (otherwise they couldn't have shared it). Sorry, but this makes no sense. If you want to keep something private, keep it private. There is absolutely no requirement whatsoever to share your reasons for resignation with anyone: not your manager, not your peers, not HR. If someone asks, the correct answer would be "none of your business" although typically you will be nicer about it: "personal reasons", "better opportunity", "doesn't feel like a good long term fit", etc.

Should I take this to HR?

No. What do you expect them to do? It's not your HR anymore in the first place. Quite likely they followed company policy anyway.

the contract was signed

If whatever contract that is specifically guaranteed confidentiality (unlikely, but possible) and the person or legal entity signing the contract violated that clause you may have legal recourse per the means specified in the contract.

You are irked. That is valid.
But what can you gain from any possible recourse. Nothing.
It is such an edge case that it doesn't apply to anyone or very, very few people.
Talk to your grandfather, not HR.
